# Editing a record within Context API & Reducer - updated context record not showing in React Native app because object has changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

The context is working for get and delete, but I'm having issues with edit.  I've found the issue, but being new to React & React Native, I'm looking for help on how to fix the problem.
It looks like the edit record is being passed to the reducer and the payload is passed within the object 'content'.  The reducer is replacing the existing record with the new data, but is stored in a different format, storing everything within the sub record 'content'.

Here is the Context:

```
   const cohortReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "getCohorts":
            return action.payload
        case "addCohort":
            return [...state, action.payload]
        case 'editCohort':
            const changedState = state.map(cohort => {
                return cohort.cohortId === action.payload.cohortId ? 
                action.payload 
                : cohort
            })
            console.log('editCohortState :', changedState)
            return changedState

        case 'deleteCohort':
            return state.filter(cohort => cohort.cohortId !== action.payload);

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

The screen that executes the edit request:

```
import { Context as CohortContext} from '../../context/CohortContext'
const { state, editCohort } = useContext(CohortContext)
try {
const content = { 
firstName: fname,
lastName: lname,
email: eml,
discAssessment: disc, 
commsStyle: disc, 
discLastRun, 
xCoordinates: xCoord, 
yCoordinates: yCoord, 
mobileXCoordinates: mobileXCoord,
mobileYCoordinates: mobileYCoord,
chartColor,
relationshipType: relType,
influenceScore: inflScore,
advocacyScore: advScore,
interactionScore: intScore,
surveyId: survId,
surveyLastRun: survRun,
userId: uId,
contact: cont }


editCohort(cohort.goalId, cohort.cohortId, content)
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Cohort (put) api error:', error)
}
```

If you look at the console.log created when the Reducer executes, it shows the updated items being consolidated under 'content' within the cohort record.

One thing, the api.put request sends the update correctly to the backend.  So, to refresh the context from the table, and the context is correct again.  But, the record is not showing immediately after the update.

Question: How do I just update the existing attributes with this command when action.payload is within 'content'

```
const changedState = state.map(cohort => {
            return cohort.cohortId === action.payload.cohortId ? 
            action.payload 
            : cohort
```

The console log results:

````
[
    {
        "cohortId": "178fb97c-ddd7-4763-ba94", 
        "content": {
            "advocacyScore": 65, 
            "chartColor": "blue", 
            "commsStyle": "Influence", 
            "contact": "c3c39d4e-c022-464f-9456-33ad64b0536d", 
            "discAssessment": "Influence", 
            "discLastRun": "Mon Apr 10 2023 08:45:49 GMT-0700", 
            "email": undefined, 
            "firstName": "Hank", 
            "influenceScore": 66, 
            "interactionScore": 44, 
            "lastName": "Zakroff", 
            "mobileXCoordinates": 117, 
            "mobileYCoordinates": -166, 
            "relationshipType": "2nd Degree Influencer", 
            "surveyId": "66c815ae-9218-43b0-8fca-f6126170546a", 
            "surveyLastRun": "Mon Apr 10 2023 04:38:20 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)", 
            "userId": "ffQZKOzrRrNCX2To2ubfV3esqr93", 
            "xCoordinates": 265, 
            "yCoordinates": 277
        }
    }, 
    
    {
        "advocacyScore": 90, 
        "chartColor": "yellow", 
        "cohortId": "5818b459-2817-445a-88c6", 
        "commsStyle": "Conscientious", 
        "contact": "a4f4f45e-9580-4c0d-9d0d-0fe98994743e", 
        "discAssessment": "Conscientious", 
        "discLastRun": "Fri Apr 07 2023 17:23:28 GMT-0700", 
        "discSelected": "Steadiness", 
        "firstName": "Anna", 
        "goalId": "d16f1f8c-c31c-49eb-8749-5f1a1212d557", 
        "goalName": "Test goal for iain@test.com with uId", 
        "influenceScore": 90, 
        "interactionScore": 90, 
        "lastName": "Haro", 
        "mobileXCoordinates": 109, 
        "mobileYCoordinates": -286, 
        "relationshipType": "Key Influencer", 
        "surveyId": "d6846773-7b7e-4f01-a047-c08facfc8943", 
        "surveyLastRun": "Fri Apr 07 2023 22:24:20 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)", 
        "userId": "ffQZKOzrRrNCX2To2ubfV3esqr93", 
        "xCoordinates": 238, 
        "yCoordinates": 92
    }
]```
````